# NServiceBus NHibernatePersister - Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TimeoutEntity'

Tags: nservicebus

We  currently set up NServiceBus with SqlTransport. We have one database for NSB , which includes a table TimeoutEntity for all endpoints . 
When we published an event, and the system will throw an exception during processing an event then NSB is trying to insert n times(n - subscribers count) the message with the same Message ID to the table TimeoutEntity this resulted in a breach of the primary key.
(Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.TimeoutEntity')

Is this a bug or incorrect configuration of the NSB ?

This our configuration:
Database:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0ex29s6r6v65nu/NSBConfiguration.png?dl=0

And configuration:

```
             var conf = Configure.With(assemblies)
            .CustomConfigurationSource(new BusConfigSource(assemblies))
            .DefineEndpointName(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[EndpointName])
            .CastleWindsorBuilder(container)
            .PurgeOnStartup(_nsbConfiguration.PurgeOnStartup)
            .FileShareDataBus(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[NServiceBusFileSharePath])
            .UnicastBus()
            .LoadMessageHandlers();

            conf.UseTransport<SqlServer>();
            conf.UseNHibernateSubscriptionPersister();
            Configure.Features.Enable<SecondLevelRetries>();
            Configure.Features.Enable<TimeoutManager>();
            Configure.Features.Enable<Sagas>();
            Configure.Features.Enable<AutoSubscribe>();


            var startableBus = conf.CreateBus();
            startableBus.Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<NServiceBus.Installation.Environments.Windows>().Install());
```

Published message has the same MessageId and TimeoutPersister(NServiceBus.Nhibernate) use it as a TimeoutId. It is correct ?

```
    public void Add(TimeoutData timeout)
    {
        var timeoutId = Guid.Empty;

        string messageId;
        if (timeout.Headers.TryGetValue(Headers.MessageId, out messageId)) 
        {
            Guid.TryParse(messageId, out timeoutId);
        }

        if (timeoutId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            timeoutId = GenerateCombGuid();
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like an incorrect configuration... What version of NServiceBus are you using? Can you share the code and the error logs, maybe on github or dropbox?

Comment: We using 4.6 version.

Comment: Is TimeoutEntity your own domain entity?

Comment: No. It's created by NServiceBus when I use SqlTransport with SLR enabled. I think I found the bug in  NServiceBus.NHibernate. Version 4.4 generate unique ID when add new item in TimeoutEntity, but in 4.5 version Id was copy from MessageId so is not unique.

Comment: https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.NHibernate/issues/67

Comment: Yup, that seems to be it!

Comment: This is now fix in NServiceBus.NHibernate 4.5.3, 5.0.1 and 6.0.1. New packages are on NuGet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. Reported on github
[link](http://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.NHibernate/issues/67)